# How to connect two field in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to connect 2 field. example In particular list there are 2 column (Car and model) Value: Car -> Audi, BMW, Mercedes Model -> Audi A3, Audi A5, BMW X3, BMW X5, Mercedes c250, Mercedes c300
lets say user select Audi then in model list should only display Audi A3, AudiA5 in list box. your advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for this requirement, insert script editor webpart into your list form and insert below sample script into script editor webpart.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var defaultCar = $('select[Title="Car"] option:selected').val();
            $('select[Title="Model"] option').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val().indexOf(defaultCar)<0) {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
                }
            })
            $('select[Title="Car"]').change(function () {
                var Car = this.value;
                console.log(Car);
                if (Car) {
                    $('select[Title="Model"] option').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).val().indexOf(Car) < 0) {
                            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeAttr('disabled').show();
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
```

[image]